# How to implement the infinite scroll in React Material Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add infinite scroll function to the react material ui autocomplete(https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/).
But i couldn't find the way to solve this problem , if anyone had already experience in this, please help me.